# Debugging Python File in Linux

Tags: python, linux, debugging

I have a .py file that I am running in Terminal on my Mac, with a json file as an argument. So I run:

```
python file.py json_file.json
```

I am setting a breakpoint in the .py program by clicking the line number, but the program doesn't seem to be breaking. Is there anything else I am supposed to add?

Comment: "Clicking the line number" - do you mean in an IDE? If so, which one? And why aren't you running your code inside that IDE rather than from the terminal, if you want to use the IDE's debugging facility?

Comment: You most probably have to run/debug the script from whatever your editor is. A breakpoint is nothing that's physically written into a file.

Comment: I am only really familiar with running files in XCode. I believe this text editor for the .py file is XCode, but I do not know how to run the file with the Json argument in anything other than Terminal.

Comment: So whenever I set breakpoints in files I run in XCode, I just click the line number and it sets a breakpoint. I am wondering what is the best way to debug in a similar fashion for this Python file, if I have to do so in Terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb), which is a command-line debugger (an enhanced version of *pdb*).

Once you install the *pudb* package via *pip*, you simply run the script with the command `python -m pudb.run my-script.py` (or specifically, for your example above, `python -m pudb.run file.py json_file.json`) and the debugger is loaded, at which point you can set breakpoints, run to cursor, inspect variables, drop into an interactive shell, etc.